# CURL 302 redirects don't work in PHP

Tags: php, curl, redirect, http-status-code-302

If you go to this link **via browser** (no adv):

`http://podbor-akkumulyatora.ru/site/submit/?filter_brand=1&filter_model=1&filter_generation=1&filter_engine=12532`

You will be redirected on

`http://podbor-akkumulyatora.ru/audi/100/4--c4-1990-1994/s4-4.2--280-hp/`

But if you go to first link **via PHP cURL**, you will be redirected to other link:

`http://podbor-akkumulyatora.ru/audi/100/4--c4-1990-1994/`

(without `s4-4.2--280-hp/` on the end!).

**Why when using cURL, external server returning different 
location (in response headers) than if I connect via browser?**

I trying to solve this whole day (really). All request headers is right, I compared them with headers which sending my browser.

My code:

```
<?php

echo 'Final URL is: <br>' . curl_query('http://podbor-akkumulyatora.ru/site/submit/?filter_brand=1&filter_model=1&filter_generation=1&filter_engine=12532')[2];

function curl_query($url, $ajax = false, $POST = null) {
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    if ($POST) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $POST);
    }

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);

    $cookies = dirname(__FILE__) . '/akb/cookie.txt';
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookies);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookies);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 YaBrowser/17.11.0.2191 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 60);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip,deflate');
    $headers = array( // Additional headers
        'Accept: '.($ajax ? 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01' : 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8'),
        'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate',
        'Accept-Language: ru,en;q=0.9',
        'Connection: keep-alive',
        'DNT: 1',
        'Host: podbor-akkumulyatora.ru',
        'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1',
    );

    if ($ajax) {
        $headers[] = 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest';
    }

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://podbor-akkumulyatora.ru/');

    $debug = false;
    if ($debug) {
        ob_start();
        $out = fopen('akb/debug.txt', 'w');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $out);
    }

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    $http_code = (int)curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    $final_url = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);

    if ($debug) {
        fclose($out);
        $debug = ob_get_clean();
    }

    curl_close($ch);
    return array($data, $http_code, $final_url);
}
```

Comment: 1. Never ever turn off certificate verification (VERIFY_PEER and HOST). 2. Use fiddler to capture the exact network activity for both attempts (curl and browser) and upload the saz file somewhere where we can download and see it. Add comments to the beginning entry of each test to indicate curl or browser.

Comment: @jhilgeman, https://www.dropbox.com/sh/02tawp6xmm5bf5u/AAA-jgFPaYi_tfBpwXG3czl9a?dl=0

Comment: The curl capture doesn't seem correct. It only has one entry, which is to a completely different web server and path. Not sure if you just captured the wrong thing, but if not, then curl isn't hitting the same URL as the browser, so I'm not sure why you think you'd get the same response...

Comment: @jhilgeman, maybe I need somehow configure Fiddler to capture PHP cURL queries? Because there are no records in Fiddler except requesting my PHP script

Comment: @jhilgeman I enabled verbose logging in cURL options. Results there: https://pastebin.com/002Xebgj

Comment: Please progress this abandoned question.   If you managed to self-solve, please post an educational answer for the benefit of future researchers.